# Select a row when data is missing

Tags: postgresql

i got a question.

I use this straight foreward query to retrieve data on a daily basis. part of the data is an ID.

For example, i got ID's 001 002 003 and 004. Every ID has some columns with data. 
I daily generate a report based on that data.
A typical day looks lke

```
ID Date Value
001 2013-07-02 900 
002 2013-07-02 800
003 2013-07-02 750 
004 2013-07-02 950
Select * 

FROM
     myTable

WHERE datum > now() - INTERVAL '2 days' and ht not in (select ht from blocked_ht)

order by ht, id;
```

Some times the import for 1 id fails. So my data looks like

```
ID Date Value
001 2013-07-02 900
003 2013-07-02 750
004 2013-07-02 950
```

Its vital to know that 1 ID is missing, visualized in my report (made in Japserreports)
So i instert an ID without a date and value 0 and eddited the query:

```
SELECT *

FROM
     "lptv_import" lptv_import

WHERE datum > now() - INTERVAL '2 days' and ht not in (select ht from negeren_ht) OR datum IS NULL

order by ht, id;
```

Now the data looks like this:

```
001 2013-07-02 900
002            800
003 2013-07-02 750
004 2013-07-02 950
```

How can i select from the tabel the row without the date WHEN ID 002 WITH a date is missing?

Hmm, this looks more compliacted than i thought...

Comment: can the table have multiple records of one id, like in your case, 002 with date and without date

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    id, coalesce(datum::text, 'NULL') as "date", "value"
from
    (
        select distinct id
        from lptv
    ) id
    left join
    lptv using (id)
where
    datum > now() - INTERVAL '2 days' 
    and not exists (select ht from negeren_ht where ht = lptv.ht)
order by id
```